# Bad adhesion only when printing many small parts "all at once" - can't use Brim

Tags: heated-bed, adhesion

There is a [similar question](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/21186/2206) First layer prints just fine, then at second or third layer the printer just unsticks the small parts and makes a mess. But the solution is "Use brim". And it sure works where brim can be used, but it can't be used in some situations.

I can print single parts of any size just fine, from small to big. I can print a lot of small parts using the "one at a time" option (complete one part before starting another) just fine, and it will be usually faster than the "all at once" (layer 0 of all parts, then layer 1 of all parts...).

Adding a bunch of brim helps, but it's not always viable. Recently I made a bunch of button caps, with manual material replacement mid-way, for  labels on them. I managed by adding so much brim they all merged into one big surface at layer 0.

But if I wanted to print an articulated "chainmail" material, or similar print-in-place articulated prints, brim will be next to impossible to remove without breaking the fragile joints merging the pieces. How to solve this problem?

Material: PLA, Printer: Longer LK5 Pro (a close Ender 3s derivative, just big). Ceramic-coated glass bed.  60C bed temp, 200C nozzle temp, Octoprint. Tried both clean bed (water+detergent then isopropyl), and coating it with glue stick, problem persists.

Comment: What's your temperature profile? Does it change after first layer?  And what about cooling profile?

Answer (score 0):

Having your printer properly calibrated, trammed and leveled and your bed perfectly cleaned is perhaps the most important, as well as using the proper z-offset, rods lubricated, relatively stable room temperature, for example not printing in front of an open window where wind at a different outdoor temperature can blow directly on your printer.

Some other potential solutions and considerations:

1. **Bed Temperature**: Slightly increase the bed temperature for the first few layers (up to 60°C for PLA) to enhance adhesion, then reduce it to the standard temperature for the subsequent layers. This can make a significant difference in the initial adhesion of small parts.
2. **Adhesion Enhancers**: Use adhesives such as glue stick or hairspray on the bed.
3. **Print Speed and Cooling Adjustments**: Reduce the printing speed for the first few layers to allow better adhesion. Simultaneously, minimize or turn off cooling fans for these initial layers. This ensures that the material has adequate time to bond to the bed before cooling and solidifying.

These methods are focused on enhancing the initial layer's adhesion to the bed, which is critical when printing multiple small parts. You probably need to experiment with these adjustments to find the optimal balance for your specific printer, filament and environment.